# Error C# ListViewItem y Task

Tags: c#, listview

El codigo funcionaba bien cuando no usaba Task, ahora me arroja este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace RPOS.Controladores
{
    class Productos
    {
        RPOS.Modelos.Productos modelo_productos;
        principal form_principal;
        ListViewItem items_productos;
        string[,] productos;
        string[] producto;
        int total_filas_array = 0;
        string nombre_producto, codigo_producto, precio1, precio2, precio3, precio4, precio5, bodega, stock, detalle, codigo_barras, proveedor, categoria;
        int respuesta_modelo;
        string sql;
        DialogResult resultado_mensajes;
        MySqlCommand comando;
        BackgroundWorker cargar_productos;
        Funciones funciones;
        Paginacion paginacion;
        int[] paginacion_result;
        public Productos()
        {

            modelo_productos = new RPOS.Modelos.Productos();
            form_principal = new principal();
            cargar_productos = new BackgroundWorker();
            funciones = new Funciones();
            paginacion = new Paginacion();
            paginacion_result = new int[2];
           // cargar_productos.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(hilo_mostarproductos);
        } 




        public async Task mostrar_productos(int opcion,string dato)
        {
            Datos.principal.lista_productos.Items.Clear();
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {

            //Limpiamos el Listview de Productos

         //   total_filas_array = modelo_productos.obtener_productos(opcion, dato).Length/14;
                   productos = modelo_productos.obtener_productos(opcion, dato);



                    for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
                    {
                    items_productos = new ListViewItem(productos[a, 1]);
                    items_productos.SubItems.Add(productos[a, 2]);
                    items_productos.SubItems.Add(productos[a, 8]);
                    items_productos.SubItems.Add(productos[a, 9]);
                    items_productos.SubItems.Add(productos[a, 10]);

                    Datos.principal.lista_productos.Items.Add(items_productos);

                    }


                productos = null;


            });

        }

        public void mostrar_producto(string codigo)
        {

            producto = modelo_productos.obtener_producto(codigo);

            Datos.principal.nombre_producto.Text = producto[1];
            Datos.principal.codigo_producto.Text = producto[2];
            Datos.principal.precio1_producto.Text = producto[3];
            Datos.principal.precio2_producto.Text = producto[4];
            Datos.principal.precio3_producto.Text = producto[5];
            Datos.principal.precio4_producto.Text = producto[6];
            Datos.principal.precio5_producto.Text = producto[7];
            Datos.principal.bodega_producto.Text = producto[8];
            Datos.principal.stock_producto.Text = producto[9];
            Datos.principal.detalle_producto.Text = producto[10];
            Datos.principal.categoria_producto.Text = producto[12];
            Datos.principal.proveedor_producto.Text = producto[13];
            Datos.principal.codigo_barras.Text = producto[14];




        }






        //En el pre_registro realizamos todo tipo de validaciones 
        public string pre_registro_producto()
        {
            nombre_producto = Datos.principal.nombre_producto.Text;
            codigo_producto = Datos.principal.codigo_producto.Text;
            precio1 = Datos.principal.precio1_producto.Text;
            precio2 = Datos.principal.precio2_producto.Text;
            precio3 = Datos.principal.precio3_producto.Text;
            precio4 = Datos.principal.precio4_producto.Text;
            precio5 = Datos.principal.precio5_producto.Text;
            bodega = Datos.principal.bodega_producto.Text;
            stock = Datos.principal.stock_producto.Text;
            detalle = Datos.principal.detalle_producto.Text;
            codigo_barras = Datos.principal.codigo_barras.Text;
            proveedor = Datos.principal.proveedor_producto.Text;
            categoria = Datos.principal.categoria_producto.Text;


            if (nombre_producto == "" || codigo_producto == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Llene todos los campos con asterisco.","Informacion",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if(bodega == "" || categoria == "")
            {
                resultado_mensajes = MessageBox.Show("Si ingresa la BODEGA o CATEGORIA del producto no podra venderlo el mismo.Desea registrarlo igualmente ?", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                if(resultado_mensajes==DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    registrar_producto();
                }


            }
            else if (precio1 == "" || precio2 == "" || precio3 == "" || precio4 == "" || precio5 == "")
            {

                resultado_mensajes = MessageBox.Show("Si no ingresa ningun PRECIO no podra venderlo el producto.Desea registrarlo igualmente ?", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                if (resultado_mensajes == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    registrar_producto();
                }


            }
            else if(Datos.principal.stock_producto.Text=="" || int.Parse(Datos.principal.stock_producto.Text)<1)
            {

                resultado_mensajes = MessageBox.Show("Si ingresa stock CERO no podra vender el producto.Desea registrarlo igualmente ?", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                if (resultado_mensajes == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    registrar_producto();
                }


            }
            else 
            {
                respuesta_modelo=modelo_productos.registrar_productos(nombre_producto,codigo_producto,precio1,precio2,precio3,precio4,precio5,bodega,stock,detalle, codigo_barras,proveedor,categoria);

                if (respuesta_modelo==1) 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Producto registrado correctamente.", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error al registrar el producto.", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                }

            }

            return "";
        }
        //Enviamos los datos de registro al modelo
        public void registrar_producto()
        {
            respuesta_modelo = modelo_productos.registrar_productos(nombre_producto, codigo_producto, precio1, precio2, precio3, precio4, precio5, bodega, stock, detalle, codigo_barras, proveedor, categoria);

            if (respuesta_modelo == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Producto registrado correctamente.", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al registrar el producto.", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }
        }
        public void inhabilitar_producto(string codigo)
        {
            modelo_productos.inhabilitar_producto(codigo);
        }
        public void habilitar_producto(string codigo)
        {
            modelo_productos.habilitar_producto(codigo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, Edita la pregunta e indica en texto el código donde te da el error. 
Así será mas fácil ayudarte, y evitarás que te cierren la pregunta por baja calidad.

Comment: Otra cosa, donde no usabas Task, en `mostrar_productos(...)` o en `obtener_productos(...)`?

Comment: No usaba Task..

Comment: obtner_productos debe retornar una consulta de  Linq. Es así?

Comment: Otra duda donde se define item_productos. No debería se local.?

Comment: Reduce el contador a 5 en mostrar_productos

Answer (score 0):

En principio parece que `modelo_productos.obtener_productos(opcion, dato)` no está pudiendo recuperar los datos, debido a posiblemente a un "*DeadLock*" por el uso de la asincronía.

prueba a utilizar `ConfigureAwait(false)` en la llamada:

```
      await Task.Run(() =>
      {
         productos = modelo_productos.obtener_productos(opcion, dato);
            for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
            {
               items_productos = new ListViewItem(productos[a, 1]);
               items_productos.SubItems.Add(productos[a, 2]);
               items_productos.SubItems.Add(productos[a, 8]);
               items_productos.SubItems.Add(productos[a, 9]);
               items_productos.SubItems.Add(productos[a, 10]);
               Datos.principal.lista_productos.Items.Add(items_productos);
            }
        productos = null;
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Rafael Acosta, resulto lo mismo

Answer (score -1):

Edicion:

El  comportamiento  que describo en mi respuesta inicial  me ocurrio en una app MVC  cuando mandaba una solicitud ajax post/get  a un metodo asincromo. Cuando la solicitud llegaba al servidor el metodo asíncrono se ejecutaba en una nueva sesión. Al volverrlo  síncrono (quitando async Task) la solicitud se hacía en la misma sesión. Pense que el problema expuesto era similar pero revisando  nuevamente el problema me doy cuenta que no es el caso. Este problema ocurre en un WindowsForm (al menos parece eso)

No obstante, en la imagen  se observa que se produce un NullPointerException en la primera línea del for  y hacia la izquierda en la parte de abajo  puede ver el valor de la variable "a" que está en 48. Se deduce que   el for  hizo 47 iteraciones  correctamente y produjo error al entrar al 48 . NullException en esa a linea   solo puede deberse a que productos[48,1]  es nulo. Ahora la pregunta es porque funciona  cuando no tiene async/await? Me parece que es porque corre con la versión del código que pusiste en  la explicación de tu problema. Si los ves el for solo es hasta 5. A no ser que compruebes  que sin async /await bajo el mismo contexto no produce error. Que la verdad no creo por la evidencia presentada.

Para solucionarlo deberías hacer foreach

```
       foreach p in productos ) }
           items_productos = new ListViewItem(p[1]);
               items_productos.SubItems.Add(p[2]);
           items_productos.SubItems.Add(p[8]);
           items_productos.SubItems.Add(p[9]);
           items_productos.SubItems.Add(p[10]);
           Datos.principal.lista_productos.Items.Add(items_productos);


     }
```